# не правильная работа html таблицы

Tags: html, веб-программирование

Всем привет. Не могу решить проблему с таблицей. Сделал 2 таблицы, вот их код:

```css
.a{
      background-color: black;
}
.s{
      background-color: white;
}
```

```html
    <table width=100% border=1 class="a">
    <tr >
        <td rowspan=4 class="s">.</td>
        <td rowspan=4 class="s">.</td>
        <td colspan=3 rowspan=2 class="s">.</td>
        <td colspan=3 class="s">.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr >
        <td colspan=3 class="s">.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr >
        <td rowspan=2 class="s">.</td>
        <td rowspan=2 class="s">.</td>
        <td rowspan=2 class="s">.</td>
        <td colspan=2 class="s">.</td>
        <td rowspan=2 class="s">.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr >
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td rowspan=5 class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s" rowspan=5>.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr >
        <td class="s" rowspan=2>.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr >
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr >
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr >
        <td colspan=4 class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
        <td class="s">.</td>
      </tr>
    </tr>
    </table >
    </br>
    <table width="100%" border="1" class="a" >
     <tr>
      <td class="s" rowspan="4">.</td>
      <td class="s" colspan="6">.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td  class="s" colspan="3">.</td>
      <td class="s" colspan="3">.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="s" colspan="2">.</td>
      <td class="s" rowspan="2">.</td>
      <td  class="s" colspan="2">.</td>
      <td class="s" rowspan="2">.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="s">.</td>
      <td class="s">.</td>
      <td class="s">.</td>
      <td class="s">.</td>
      
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="s">.</td>
      <td class="s">.</td>
      <td class="s">.</td>
      <td class="s">.</td>
      <td class="s">.</td>
      <td class="s">.</td>
      <td class="s">.</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

в каждый td поставлена точка. и так таблица работает.если убрать точку из тега тд, то таблица стянется вверх. почему так?

Comment: Если заменить точки на `&nbsp;` ?

Comment: @br3t , спасибо, работает, но почему не работает без символов?

Comment: У пустой ячейки нет высоты. Как альтернатива - можете задать высоту ячейки в стилях. `.s { height: 20px; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строка таблицы будет принимать наименьшую ширину\высоту, которая возможна. Но если ширина у вас указана - растягивать таблицу на 100%, то вот высота ячейки - нет, поэтому она и принимает без контента минимально возможную высоту. С контентом - принимает минимально возможную высоту + высота строк (line-height). Как вариант - укажите просто height:22px; и тогда минимальная высота будет 22 пикселя. Можете указать и padding, но тогда с контентом это будет сумма паддингов сверху и снизу + высота строки, а без контента просто сумма паддингов

```css
.a{
  background-color: black;
}
.s{
  background-color: white;
}
td{
  height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>no</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="zux.css">
</head>
<body>

<table width=100% border=1 class="a">
  <tr >
    <td rowspan=4 class="s"></td>
    <td rowspan=4 class="s"></td>
    <td colspan=3 rowspan=2 class="s"></td>
    <td colspan=3 class="s"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr >
    <td colspan=3 class="s"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr >
    <td rowspan=2 class="s"></td>
    <td rowspan=2 class="s"></td>
    <td rowspan=2 class="s"></td>
    <td colspan=2 class="s"></td>
    <td rowspan=2 class="s"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr >
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan=5 class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s" rowspan=5></td>
  </tr>

  <tr >
    <td class="s" rowspan=2></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr >
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr >
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr >
    <td colspan=4 class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
    <td class="s"></td>
  </tr>
</table >

<table width="100%" border="1" class="a" >
    <tr>
        <td class="s" rowspan="4"></td>
        <td class="s" colspan="6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td  class="s" colspan="3"></td>
        <td class="s" colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="s" colspan="2"></td>
        <td class="s" rowspan="2"></td>
        <td  class="s" colspan="2"></td>
        <td class="s" rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="s"></td>
        <td class="s"></td>
        <td class="s"></td>
        <td class="s"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="s"></td>
        <td class="s"></td>
        <td class="s"></td>
        <td class="s"></td>
        <td class="s"></td>
        <td class="s"></td>
        <td class="s"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: И да, в первой таблице еще был лишний закрывающий <tr>